# AWS SNS Support for Token Based Connection to APNs

Tags: apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

Does SNS support token based connection to APNs?

I see the AWS documentation on certificate based connection to APNs, but don't see any way to connect via tokens.

Is this available? If so, is there any AWS documentation on this because I can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

Currently *(i.e as of 07th March 2020)* Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) doesn't support Token Based Connection (.p8) to APNs

I would like to refer you to another AWS service called [Amazon Pinpoint](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/09/amazon-pinpoint-broadens-reach-of-multi-channel-messaging-with-new-support-for-amazon-device-messaging-baidu-cloud-push-and-apns-sandbox-and-p8-token-authentication-for-apns/) which I know support Token Based Connection (.p8) to APNs.

Answer (score 0):

SNS now supports token-based authentication for APNs, using .p8 files. You can find more information about it here: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/amazon-sns-token-authentication-api-mobile-notifications/